# Getting the Exeption - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#

I am working in a client server application

In main method i am calling the _exampleMessages[] method as like below mentioned Example:

```
 String messageType = "Balance Inquiry";
 try
 {
     person.RequestString = _exampleMessages[messageType];
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

and i declared the _exampleMessages[] method as bellow

```
public static Dictionary<String, String> _exampleMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        //            { "Transfer Inquiry",
        //@"01 01 60 00 05 80 53 01 00 30 20 05 80 20 C0 10 07 39 10 00 00 07 25 00 00 00 00 31 07 00 21 00 05 00
        //37 49 91 87 02 73 00 27 3C D6 2B 27 1A 0A 38 08 00 80 12 40 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 35 31 32
        //33 34 35 31 32 33 34 35 77 BB AA 66 78 3B D7 CC 00 06 30 30 33 31 30 37 01 56 37 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
        //32 33 31 34 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 32 33 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
        //            },
        //            { "Transfer",
        //@"01 01 60 00 05 80 53 02 00 30 20 05 80 20 C0 10 07 40 10 00 00 07 25 00 00 00 00 31 07 00 21 00 05 00
        //37 49 91 87 02 73 00 27 3C D6 2B 27 1A 0A 38 08 00 80 12 40 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 35 31 32
        //33 34 35 31 32 33 34 35 77 BB AA 66 78 3B D7 CC 00 06 30 30 33 31 30 37 01 56 37 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
        //32 33 31 34 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 44 45 53
        //54 49 4E 41 54 49 4F 4E 20 4E 41 4D 45 20 47 45 4E 45 52 41 54 45 44 20 20 20 20 31 32 33 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 33 31 34 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
        //            },
        //            { "TransferSB",
        //@"01 1B 60 00 05 80 53 02 00 B0 20 05 80 20 C0 10 07 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 40 10 00 00 07 25 00 00 00
        //00 31 07 00 21 00 05 00 37 49 91 87 02 73 00 27 3C D6 2B 27 1A 0A 38 08 00 80 12 40 31 32 33 34 31 32 33
        //34 31 32 33 34 35 31 32 33 34 35 31 32 33 34 35 77 BB AA 66 78 3B D7 CC 00 06 30 30 33 31 30 37 01 56 37
        //38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 33 31 34 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 44 45 53 54 49 4E 41 54 49 4F 4E 20 4E 41 4D 45 20 47 45 4E 45 52 41 54 45 44 20 20 20 20
        //31 32 33 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 33 31 34 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
        //20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 54 52 41 4E 53 41 43 54 49 4F
        //4E 20 4E 4F 54 45"
        //            },
        //            { "Balance Inquiry",
        //@"00 5D 60 00 05 80 53 01 00 20 20 05 80 20 C0 10 05 31 10 00 00 31 07 00 21 00 05 00 37 49 91 87 02 73
        //00 27 3C D6 2B 27 1A 0A 38 08 00 80 12 40 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34 35 31 32 33 34 35 31 32 33
        //34 35 77 BB AA 66 78 3B D7 CC 00 06 30 30 33 31 30 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
        //            },
        //            { "Logon",
        //@"00 1F 60 00 05 80 53 08 00 20 20 01 00 00 80 00 00 92 00 00 00 31 07 00 05 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34"
        //            }
    };
```

i am getting below exception:

> **The given key was not present in the dictionary. how can i solve the error**

Comment: Try uncomment your dictionary's initialization list

Comment: As you have commented the initialization of dictionary. Hence it is empty. So it throws the error.

Comment: tahnk you ,it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the error by adding the value with the key, you search for, first. Take a look at this example:

```
var exampleMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // it's empty

// if you uncomment the line below, you'll get an exception
// var value = exampleMessages["someKey"];

// because you need to put the value with that key first!
exampleMessages["someKey"] = "someValue";

// now there's no exception
var value = exampleMessages["someKey"];

// it outputs "someValue"
Console.WriteLine(value);
```